# Cross Database Security

Tags: sql-server, database, cross-database

I have 2 databases X&Y. I have a user on X which needs to access Table in Y through a view in X. X has a synonym built to access table on Y. I need the user to access the view,not access the synonym (i acheived this through DENY GRANT),not access the table in the Y database directly (GRANT permissions are not helping).Both the Databases are on same instance in SQL Server-2012.
Is there any way out Linked Server on the same instance are not possible.

User->Database X->View->Synonym->Database Y->Should see Data
User->Database Y->Table->Should not see Data

Comment: Can't you use stored procedure instead of view? This way you don't need granting explicit permission to table Y to user X.

Comment: I need to give the view to enduser to make reports,they need only access to the specific set of tables in X and selective records in the table present in Y. X tables isnt a problem,user should not see all the records in Y.They need to join the tables to create the reports.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating two views with the same name (V_W) in both the databases.I wrote the logic for fetching my required set of data from X in the view created in Y.I created the view in X with a simple call to view in Y and it worked.Not the best of the process at least i achieved my purpose